# sort rows in 'VI' editor

Tags: text-editor, vi

If i have to sort following rows on the basis of values on left of '='. But the sorting should expand the selection to column after '=' simultaneously. Thtz is we dnt have to sort column after '=' ::

```
50599=1000000  
50454=00000054  
50080=00005464  
50098=00000875  
50661=00000665  
50788=10000035  
50988=10000006  
50994=10000656  
57009=00000005  
57022=10000008  
57040=10000005  
57000=10000005  
57060=10000089  
57067=10005640  
57102=00000765  
57190=00000867
```

This needs to be done in 'VI' editing the file.

RESULT should be ::

```
50080=00005464    
50098=00000875  ...etc.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This answer is coming 2 years late, but might still be relevant, in visual mode select the block you want to sort and run:

```
:!sort
```

Answer (score 36):

Try:

```
:%!sort
```

It will sort according the whole line alphabetically. If you want to sort numerically (i.e. the number in the first column can have different widt), then try:

```
:%!sort -n
```

Don't worry about the `=`, it will not modify any line, it will just change their order.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following to see the sorted output:

```
:!sort %
```

Explanation:

- `:` : to enter ex mode.
- `!` : allows you to run a shell
  command.
- `%` : the name of the file currently
  open.

To sort the file by changing it you can redirect its output to a temp file and then copy its content back to the original file:

```
:!(sort %>/tmp/tmp;cp -f /tmp/tmp %)
```

Comment: Hmm, the file got corrupted. I forgot to tell you sthin : this is a xml file which has some attributes in it like ::

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly when in the last eight years `vi` built this in, but you can now run:

```
:sort n
```

to sort numerical entries instead of using `:!` to run the `sort` command. See `:help sort`