# vim sort based on given column

Tags: vim, yaml

Suppose I have this section in my yaml file

```
hdkkhj50599: 1000000  
504sdaaf54: 00000054  
pppppp: 00005464
```

I want to sort these lines based on the values after colons.

None of the suggested solutions in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861503/sort-rows-in-vi-editor) worked for me.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim's internal [`:sort`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asort) provides options for what you want: the `n` flag is for sorting decimal numbers (instead of alphabetially, though it wouldn't matter in your 0-padded example), a `/.../` pattern is skipped at the beginning; we non-greedily match up to the first colon and whitespace:

```
:sort n/.\{-}: /
```

Answer (score 2):

With vim sorting command:

- `:sort /^.\{-}:/`

You can sort them by using linux command:

- `:%!sort -t: -k2`

---

For more see `:help sort`

Answer (score 0):

In case you're on linux you can try the following in vim  (will call external sort command)

```
:%!sort -g
```

Obviously you can replace % with the definition of your lines-range e.g: for lines 5 to 10 you would do:

```
:5,10!sort -g
```